# python - take a string and dictionary and return an encrypted version of the string

Tags: python, string, encryption, dictionary

encrypt the string with the dictionary so that it returns kjyyp

```
def encrypt(s,d)
    d = { 'a' : 'm', 'b' : 'd', 'c' : 'l', 'd' : 'x', 'e' : 'j', 
          'f' : 't', 'g' : 'u', 'h' : 'k', 'i' : 'z', 'j' : 'd', 
          'k' : 'o', 'l' : 'y', 'm' : 'i', 'n' : 'v', 'o' : 'p', 
          'p' : 'q', 'q' : 'f', 'r' : 'c', 's' : 'r', 't' : 'b', 
          'u' : 'j', 'v' : 'w', 'w' : 'n', 'x' : 'h', 'y' : 's', 'z' : 'a' }
    # ?

print encrypt('hello',d)
```

this is what i have so far

```
def encrypt(s,d):
    d = { 'a' : 'm', 'b' : 'd', 'c' : 'l', 'd' : 'x', 'e' : 'j', 
          'f' : 't', 'g' : 'u', 'h' : 'k', 'i' : 'z', 'j' : 'd', 
          'k' : 'o', 'l' : 'y', 'm' : 'i', 'n' : 'v', 'o' : 'p', 
          'p' : 'q', 'q' : 'f', 'r' : 'c', 's' : 'r', 't' : 'b', 
          'u' : 'j', 'v' : 'w', 'w' : 'n', 'x' : 'h', 'y' : 's', 'z' : 'a' }
    for i in d:
       return s
print encrypt('Hello',d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dictionaries are key value pairs d['a'] = m 
so just iterate throught the letters in the word(s) and substitue

```
word = "" 
for letter in s.lower(): 
    word += d[letter]
return word
```

or --

```
 return "".join([ d[letter] for letter in s.lower() ])
```

**edit**

```
word ="" 
for letter in s: 
    word += d[letter] if letter in d else "?"
return word
```

Comment: now if you were to print ecrypt('Hello'd) with a capital it should return ?kyyp.........def encrypt(s,d):
 word = ''
 for i in s.lower():
  if i in d[i]:
   word += d[i]
  return ''.join([ d[i] for i in s.lower() ])
  else:
   

 
d = { 'a' : 'm', 'b' : 'd', 'c' : 'l', 'd' : 'x', 'e' : 'j', 'f' : 't', 'g' : 'u', 'h' : 'k', 'i' : 'z', 'j' : 'd', 'k' : 'o', 'l' : 'y', 'm' : 'i', 'n' : 'v', 'o' : 'p', 'p' : 'q', 'q' : 'f', 'r' : 'c', 's' : 'r', 't' : 'b', 'u' : 'j', 'v' : 'w', 'w' : 'n', 'x' : 'h', 'y' : 's', 'z' : 'a' }       
print encrypt('hello',d)

Comment: i have it in an if statement and am trying to appen("?")